# Receiving Windows Message in class library asynchronously in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, class-library, wndproc

Writing a class library, in which function return a string value based on window message received using the window handle.

Currently, not able to wait asynchronously to receive window message.
Below is pseudo code which is being used.

```
 namespace TestIntialization

 {
    public class Example : Form
    {
        string status = "";
        public string init()
        {
            Example ex = new Example();
            ex.intialise(this.Handle);    // this handle used for receiving window message

            // Need to wait for wndProc handler to update string value.             
            return status;
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x2000)
            {
                status = "SUCESS";
            }
            if (m.Msg == 0x2001)
            {
                status = "FAILURE";
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Tried option like Thread.sleep,EventWaitHandle's WaitOne function but this function block the running thread. 
I am receiving expected window message in WndProc handler but value are reaching message handler only after exiting init function.
So not able to inform calling application about success or failure status.

Comment: What version of .NET/VS are you using? The first thing that comes to mind is `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: i am using .net 4.5. btw "TaskCompletionSource" has to be used along with async method which take only void or task as return type. In my case i have to return value as string..

Comment: If you have some added requirement, you need to illustrate to _precisely_ with your code example. Note that returning a `string` (or any other value) is not mutually exclusive with `async`. The normal pattern is to `await` the task, which unpacks the return value, allowing evaluation as the plain return value, not as a `Task<T>` instance. In any case, you can't "wait" per se without blocking the running thread, which you already say you don't want to do. `async` is a natural fit here, as it allows "waiting" without "blocking".

Comment: `init` creates a new instance. The status returned by init is not the status that is set in the WndProc of the created instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve event handling in synchronously, by calling [Application.DoEvents()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

but there are several unwanted consequence while using the Application.DoEvents() function. i am using this form for only receiving window message,form wont be visible to end user. so i am not getting any issue as of now.

```
            while(!flag) // flag value will be set true  after processing wnd proc message.
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
```